# Как спарсить содержимое iframe #document используя requests? (python)

Tags: python, iframe

Как спарсить внутри тега iframe данные в теге #document? requests его не видит, а в инспекторе в мозилле он есть.
Можно ли это сделать не прибегая к selenium?

Comment: Прочитайте свой вопрос, Вас ни чего не смущает?

Comment: если вас что-то в вопросе смущает, то напишите, не стесняйтесь, постараюсь объяснить и исправить

Comment: приходится угадывать что Вы имеете в виду

Comment: вот в этом фрейме есть #document с данными фрейма
https://prnt.sc/muyuv1
он виден только через Инспектор в Мозилле, а через запрос requests его нет. Возможно ли как-то его получить?

Comment: Если iframe загружен с другого домена, то в дикой природе - никак

Comment: т.е. таки requests это не умеет, а не я не знаю как? ) и без вариантов придётся подключать магию selenium ))

Comment: @Олег не пробовали по запросам узнать откуда Iframe подгружается?

Comment: В первую очередь придётся определить, откуда загружается дочерний документ в iframe. После того, как станет известен URL этого ресурса, его нужно загрузить библиотекой requests, и дальше уже можно будет разобрать его каким-либо парсером.

Comment: в том то и проблема, я не могу понять откуда попадают данные и как их вытянуть из #document, там куча нюансов (( а тут в личку нельзя написать?

Comment: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/183314)